# Does the webpage keeps loading while sending a large set of emails through SMTP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, large-data

When an user on my CodeIgniter webapp submits a particluar action, other users (not many yet, but will be more than 1000 in a few weeks) get a notification through email. This notification is personal, so i loop through the users and create and send the mail for each.

In this foreach loop i save each mail in the DB and send the email with my Google Apps SMTP server, as can be seen in the following config:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = '465';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'test@mydomain.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'testpass';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
```

Now my first question is: When the user submits the action, does he have to wait untill all messages are sent? Or will these emails will be sent to the mail server and the page is finished loading within a few seconds (when creating mails and saving them do DB is done)?

Second question: is this the right way to do it? Can i be sure that all mails will be succesfully delivered?

Can anyone help me with this or send me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that Google Apps has limits on the amount of mail you can send. Sending 1000 emails based on the actions of one user could quickly exceed those limits. See [this page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en)

Comment: Good point. Maybe i should use my own SMTP server (of the dedicated server, where the webpages are also hosted).. But this still doesnt answer all my questions.. Anyone?